# Docker container with HBA card

Tags: docker, vmware, san

How can i attach a HBA card (which is on my physical server running on centos 7) to a docker container? As I'm doing POC for migration to docker from existing environment this is much needed. It's similar to direct IO in VMware ESXi(Attaching a physical hba to VM can be done via Direct I/O).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker isn't a hypervisor, containers aren't VMs, and "attaching devices" to a container doesn't necessarily make sense -- a container is just a process running on your host.

You can expose a device node in `/dev` to a container using the `--device` flag to `docker run`, although exposing a block device inside a container usually leads to other complications (e.g., a normal container can't mount filesystems, so you would need to run it with `--privileged`, which may or may not be acceptable form a security perspective depending on your environment).

For storage, it is more common to mount devices on the *host*, and then expose those filesystems to container as Docker volumes (`-v /host/path:/container/path`).

Comment: Agreed with "docker isn't a Hypervisor & container aren't VMs"... and this is new to me.. "a container is just a process".. mounting all my devices to  host systems isn't allowed in my env. The option of exposing devices is pretty interesting ,i gonna script that :) , i thought there might be some other option like hba can be another resource . Will update on my experience after exposing the  device